NodeJS VM Context Script Execution Reference Error
I have a class that I am loading in to the a global vm context and I am executing a script within the shared context. Works fine when things are correct. But if I accidentally forget to define a variable when using one of the setters, I get a reference error and the application crashes.
const document = new document('users');
document.fetch('0939e8bde2f74213a0bd75bea8d82f8b').then(() => {
    document.setValue('middleName', bob); //bob is not defined
});

setValue is never executed. I have tried several ways to capture the error and no luck. I have tried added try/catch to the wrappedScriptContent. I have tried a try/catch within the async function. For now I have settle on the process.on but that doesn't give me any details.
Here is my executeScript method as it stands.
async executeScript(script) {
    const context = vm.createContext({...this.sharedContext});
    const wrappedScriptContent = `
        (async function() {
          ${script}
        })();`;
    try {
        const scriptObject = new vm.Script(wrappedScriptContent);
        scriptObject.runInContext(context, { timeout: 5000, displayErrors: true });
        return { success: true, result: '' };
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(`Error executing script: ${error}`);
    }
}

Is there a way to handle errors, known or not known? I am looking for a way to handle errors gracefully and try to provide detailed logging.
